# iOS - call one class from another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I want to call class name TabViewController from class name "ROOTVIEWCONTROLLER"
I want to do this because I want to make TabBarController dynamically. So I want to handle all tab related activity in class name TabViewController So from rootviewcontroller I want to access method  of TabViewController which handles the tab.
Can any one tell me how it can be done.
And where I write the code in rootviewcontroller to do this

Comment: How about you create a Navigation-based app and the code will be generated automatically for you. Analyse it it has comments, and do some navigation tutorials .

Answer (score 0):

create object of tabviewcontroller in the rootviewcontroller and push the tabviewcontroller .

Comment: thanks but can u write the line of for that code here as i m newbie i m facing problem on syntax

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the self.tabBarController if you are just trying to get an instance of the tabbarcontroller.